I want to change my Ubuntu install from Legacy to UEFFI
I use a Dell XPS 13 9350 and I installed Ubuntu 24.04.1 DESKTOP LTS without knowing about legacy bios or UEFI.
I had a virus issue on my previous windows installation and decided to install Ubuntu, during the the install I had some issues, I used the erase disk and install Ubuntu option but due to existing partitions the install kept failing so I booted from a live USB and deleted all partitions.
I now want to dual boot win 11 and I read about update issues with legacy mode. I wish to have my Ubuntu on EFI Mode now.
My partitioning is GPT (at Least that's what I see when I enter disks).
I'm asking a lot but can someone help me explain how I can create an EFI partition, and safely move my Ubuntu to EFI.

Product: Ubuntu Noble Numbat LTS 24.04.1, I used the default installer. Secure boot was disabled.

This question is similar to: In a dual boot system, how does the BIOS choose which bootloader to run?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I'm sorry, I installed the desktop product.

If on gpt drive, only difference is version of grub. Grub in BIOS mode on gpt requires the 1MB unformatted bios_grub partition. Grub in UEFI boot mode requires an ESP - efi system partition FAT32, with boot,esp flags. If on same drive as Windows in UEFI mode you have an ESP as only one per drive is normally allowed. After creating ESP, if you do not have one, probably easiest to boot live installer in UEFI mode & use Boot-Repair to totally reinstall grub. Or uninstall grub & install grub-efi-amd64. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

This will not be a complete answer. It is a description of my experience which in some ways is similar to yours.
Considering only desktop installations as opposed to servers which (I believe) (may) use different installers.
Just to clarify, Ubuntu-desktop-installer 22.04 (UDI22.04) uses the Ubiquity installer & Ubuntu-desktop-installer 24.04 (UDI24.04) uses the Flutter installer.
I started with an BIOS/MBR system and decided to upgrade my system to GPT/UEFI.
This was a manual install as I have multiple OS with a common /home.
So I began by converting the disk using gdisk ...to GPT and them started the install using UDI24.04.
When it came to manually creating a UEFI partition there was no way to do this which lead me to believe it would not install as a GPT/UEFI install. To get around this I decided to start again and install the UEFI partition using gparted but I was not happy I could get this set correctly with the correct file system (and UEFI flag). So eventually I ended up first doing a minimal install of 22.04 using UDI22.04 which does allow you to create a UEFI partition followed by a second install on top of it using UDI24.04.
This all installed successfully and I now have a working secure-boot system.
